# URL segment - User Profiles - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, user-profile

I'm trying to create user profiles for my site where the URL is something like

> mysite.com/user/ChrisSalij

Currently my controller looks like so:

```
<?php   
class User extends Controller {
   function user(){
      parent::Controller();
   }
   
   function index(){
      $data['username'] =  $this->uri->segment(2);

      if($data['username'] == FALSE) {
         /*load default profile page*/
      } else {
         /*access the database and get info for $data['username']*/
         /*Load profile page with said info*/
      }//End of Else
   }//End of function
}//End of Class
?>
```

At the moment I'm getting a 404 error whenever i go to;

> mysite.com/user/ChrisSalij

I think this is because it is expecting there to be a method called ChrisSalij.
Though I'm sure I'm misusing the `$this->uri->segment();` command too

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the controller is looking for a function called ChrisSalij.

A few ways to solve this:

1. change

   function index(){
   $data['username'] =  $this->uri->segment(2);

to be

```
function index($username){ 
$data['username'] =  $username;
```

and use the URL of mysite.com/user/index/ChrisSalij

2. if you don't like the idea of the index being in the URL you could change the function to be called a profile or the like, or look into using [routing](http://www.codeignitor.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

and use something along the lines of

```
$route['user/(:any)'] = "user/index/$1";
```

to correctly map the URL of `mysite.com/user/ChrisSalij`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. I feel like an idiot for not thinking of passing through the function :P